# Create VIEW that SELECT from VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql

what are the cons of creating view from another view?

code example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS 
 SELECT * from table1;
```

and then :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view2 AS 
 SELECT * from view1;
```

Of course it's not views like this example, but is this a good strategy?

Comment: Why do you think this might not be a good strategy?  There are many reasons to create a view that selects from another view.

Comment: For postgres, there is nothing wrong with this approach. The query plan for `select from view2` will effectively be rewritten as `select * from table1`. Just check the resulting plans.

Comment: I don't know, I would like to hear someone else's opinion on this matter. Maybe when you change a view that has other dependents you'll have to make modifications through all views?

Comment: You might draw out more discussion on this at programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The areas I keep in mind when using views are 1. If view2 has a bug or runs really slow view1 will inherit these things when view1 references view2. 2. If you use view within view within view and there's a bug way deep down in the hierarchy it can be hard to find. These really have nothing to do with views but with dependency relationships when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If your base view is doing a complicated join of two or more tables and your new view needs the same data, then it can definitely be a very good strategy to use. You save yourself the effort of need to do the same join again.

For a single table or a simple join, it isn't a bad or good idea. It's valid and if that's the way you want to do things....